# Use number from HTML text box in JavaScript equation

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some HTML code:

```
<input type="number" id="height">
```

I want to take whatever is entered in this box and use it as an int/float etc. Lets say I enter "2". Heres the JavaScript code:

```
var test;
var a;
test = document.getElementById('height').value;
a = 2 + test;
```

When I print a, I get 22. This makes sense, but I want 4. In other words, I want test to be treated as an int/float (whatever is entered in the text box). Is there an HTML input type that will do this for me, or do I have to change it another way (like JavaScript commands).

Answer (score 2):

Use the **plus** sign `(+)` a.k.a the `unary plus` operator as the first token for the variable assignment **(rvalue)**, `test = +document.getElementById('height').value`

From `developer.mozilla.org`:

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand **but attempts to converts it into a number**, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

#### Working Example

```js
var test = +document.getElementById("height").value;
var a;

a = 2 + test;
alert(a);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="height" value="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `test` is a string, not a number. Use `Number()` to convert it to a number:

```
a = 2 + Number(test);
```

For your information, [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is not [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) - JavaScript is more for browsers, while Java is generally applied to more general situations - the syntax for each is vaguely similar, but still different. You are using *JavaScript*.